# Quadratic Formula: Word Problem.

Tags: quadratics

A person decides to build a horse corral using a barn for one side. Has has 30m of fencing materials and wants the corral to have an area of 100m^2. What are the dimensions of the corral?

- Let width = x
- Let length = y
- y=30-2x.

That's all I could come up with. Would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Be careful.  $y = 30 - 2x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  The area of a rectangle is $A = lw$.  You know that $A = 100~\text{m}^2$, $l = 30 - 2x$, and $w = x$.  Solve the resulting quadratic equation for $x$ to find the possible values of the width, then use the formula $y = 30 - 2x$ to solve for the length.